# R main.font does not work with cdplot() - does anyone know a workaround to change from bold to plain in a cdplot plot title?

Tags: r, plot

In base R the default font face for the main title of a plot is bold:

```
plot(1:10, main = "Foo")
```

I can change the font face to plain using

```
plot(1:10, main = "Foo", font.main = 1)
```

However, the same method for changing bold to plain does not work with cdplot()

```
## NASA space shuttle o-ring failures
fail <- factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
                 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
               levels = 1:2, labels = c("no", "yes"))
temperature <- c(53, 57, 58, 63, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 70,
                 70, 70, 72, 73, 75, 75, 76, 76, 78, 79, 81)

## CD plot
cdplot(fail ~ temperature, main="bw = default", font.main = 1)
```

The title remains bold and I get the error message *"extra argument ‘font.main’ will be disregarded"*. I have also tried `expression(plain("Foo"))` but the problem is that I have a for-loop generating lots of plots, the title comes from `main = paste("some text", i)` and `expression(plain...` can't handle the iterable, so the title of each plot will then be "some text i". Does anyone know some other workaround to change the title font face to plain, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `cdplot()` doesn't pass further graphical parameters to `par`. Hence, you need to use other low-level graphical functions (e.g. `title()`) to customize your plot.

```r
cdplot(fail ~ temperature)
title("bw = default", font.main = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: That has worked perfectly with my for loops, too -  thank you very much, @Darren Tsai!